# Firebase Realtime database - tableview update all the cell data if new data added

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a group chat app and trying to fetch the last message from a node to display the last message under the group name. Everything is working fine. When the group receives a new message, the last message is showing in the correct group and some other random groups as well. If I open the correct group and come back, all the other groups are showing the correct last message. Kindly help me with the below code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:GroupsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GroupsTableViewCell") as! GroupsTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    var user: Groupslist
    if groupList.count > 0 {
        user = groupList[indexPath.row]

        cell.lbl_name_group.text = user.name;
        cell.view_count.isHidden = true

        GetLastMsg(groupID: user.group_id ?? "", cell: cell)
        cell.img_group.image = UIImage.init(named:"final_grp")
      GetUnReadMsgCount(groupID: user.group_id ?? "", cell: cell)
    }
    return cell
}
```

groupList contains the list of groups which is fetched from firebase on viewWillAppear.

```
func GetLastMsg(groupID  : String, cell : GroupsTableViewCell){
    let userRef2 = rootRef2.child("message").child(groupID).queryLimited(toLast: 1)
    userRef2.observe( .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let _ = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        print("children count: \(snapshot.children.allObjects.count)")

        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let message = Message()


            let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
            let text = value["text"] as? String ?? "Name not found"
            let mimType = value["mimType"] as? String
            let name_doc = value["name_doc"] as? String ?? "file.file"
            message.text = text
            message.mimType = mimType
            message.name_doc = name_doc
            message.timestamp_group = (value["timestamp"] as! NSNumber)

            print(value["idSender"] as? String)
            print(message.name_doc)
            var  msg_last = ""
            //    cell.lbl_lastmsg.text = msg_last
            if message.mimType == "image/jpeg" {
                msg_last = "Image"
                cell.img_small_width.constant=28
                cell.img_small.image = UIImage(named: "im")
            }else if message.mimType == "audio/3gpp" {
                msg_last = "Audio"
                cell.img_small_width.constant=28
                cell.img_small.image = UIImage(named: "mi")
            }else if message.mimType == "video/mp4" {
                msg_last = "Video"
                cell.img_small_width.constant=28
                cell.img_small.image = UIImage(named: "vi")
            }else if message.mimType == "application/pdf" {
                let name_docs = message.name_doc!.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)
                msg_last = name_docs.last!
                cell.img_small_width.constant=28
                cell.img_small.image = UIImage(named: "doc")
            }else if mimType == nil{
                msg_last = message.text!
                cell.img_small_width.constant=0
            }
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.lbl_lastmsg.text = msg_last
            }
          }
          }
    })
   }
```

New method:

```
  func GetUnReadMsgCount(groupID : String, cell : GroupsTableViewCell)  {

    rootRef2.child("group_message_unread").child(current_user!).child(groupID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(snapshot.children.description)
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.view_count.isHidden = false
                cell.lbl_count.text = String(snapshot.childrenCount)
              //  self.tbl_groups.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
//                    self.tbl_groups.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior. In a `.observe( .value` listener, the snapshot is always the complete data at the path. So when you add a child node, the snapshot fires with the entire new data at `userRef2`.

You have two main options to not get duplicates in your UI:

1. Clear all messages when there is an update, before adding the data to the table again. So that'd be right before `for snap in snapshot.children` in your code. This is by far the simplest way to solve the problem if duplicate rows, but may lead to some flashing in your UI.
2. [Listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events), instead of observing the entire value. With this you'll get a single `.childAdded` event for the new child, you can get rid of the `for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects` and just add the singular new child node to the table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Is that the right way to call the firebase function in the cellforrow method? To test your solution, I have used another method to get the count of the new unread message, and used .childAdded but still when I go inside the chat group and come back If a receive a new message, the message count reflects in other group also. Any idea? I have updated my code. @Frank

Comment: Are you reattaching the observer? Because in that case it will indeed refire `.childAdded` for every child again. If you only want to listen for new messages, you'll need to change the listener for that. Have a look at these question about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+only+new

Comment: Yes, I am removing the observer when the screen disappears. Thanks for the link but that's doesn't help me. The problem occurs only when I go inside any chat group and come back then if a new message comes, the last message appearing in multiple cells.